# Why replicas perform full resync when persistence enabled master is restarted?

Tags: redis

I have 1 master with rdb persistence enabled (but no sentinels) and a couple of slaves. When master is restarted, slaves attempt a partial resync, but couldn't because the master restarts with a new replication ID. And a full resync is performed. Wondering why is a full resync happening here ? Shouldn't master come up with the same replication ID as before and then slave can perform partial resync to match it's offset with the last snapshot of master ?
Positing here, haven't got any response yet on [r/redis](https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/9mqkqt/why_replicas_perform_full_resync_when_persistence/)